# How to check a signed CSR with openssl?

Tags: openssl

I just learned that a CSR can be signed. See this [Why is a CSR signed and which key is used for signing?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40457/why-is-a-csr-signed-and-which-key-is-used-for-signing/64583)

I tried to check the csr with below openssl command, but failed with errors "139942025398160:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:707:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST"

> openssl req -in signed_csr_file.scsr -noout -verify

Does anyone know how to check signed csr with openssl ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show a test CSR. Note that questions about command line usage belong on the [superuser](https://superuser.com) site instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there are several certificate-request schemes (and formats) in use. Are you sure this file is supposed to be a CSR in the specific format supported by `req` namely [PKCS10/rfc2986 et pred](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986)?

Second, what is actually in the file? Is it actually in PEM format [as described in wikipedia's second paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) i.e. a five-dashes-BEGIN-something line, some base64, and a five-dashes-END-something line, and if so what exactly is the 'something'? Is it `CERTIFICATE REQUEST` or `NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST` or something else? Is the PEM format exactly correct (no missing, altered, or extra characters within the lines of the PEM block -- extra *lines* before or after are okay)?

If the file is not PEM format, what is it? If it contains unprintable characters, use a hex dump or similar. If you don't recognize it, post it, or at least the first 50-100 bytes, for us to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Yes you are right, I didn't notice that the file is a base64 encoded xml payload, which contains the actual csr request.

Thanks, Please ignore my question.